# Make an button to go forward and one to go backwards of an array?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html, button

I'm trying to make the array go backward with a second html button but for some reason I can't, this code makes the Div change color even the same color as many times as you wish. Right now my doubt is how to make it cycle backwards or decrement some how?

```
   <head>

   <title></title>
   <style>#placeDiv{width:100px;height:100px;}</style>
   </head>

   <body>
   <div id = "placeDiv">ok</div>
   <button onclick="forward()">Forward</button>
   <script>
     var myArray = ["black","yellow","black","red","blue"];
     var i = 0;
     function forward(){
     if(myArray.length <= i) i=0;

       document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i++];
       };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not really clear on what it is you are asking/trying to do.  Do you think you could make a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: The array contains "black" twice, is that by design?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jobson111/84Rwy/)

Comment: When I mentioned the same color, I meant that if you repeat the same color, you get it repeated as many times possible even if it's in a row, which is what I meant, that is the repetition of colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the complete correct implementation of the thing you asked with the jsfiddle link.

HTML

```
  <div id = "placeDiv">ok</div>
   <button onclick="forward()">Forward</button>
   <button onclick="backward()">Backward</button>
```

JS

```
var myArray = ["black","yellow","green","red","blue"];
     var i = 0;
 document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
     forward=function(){

         if(i == myArray.length-1) 
         {i=0;}
         else
         {i=i+1;}

       document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];
       };
backward=function(){

     if(i == 0)
     {i=myArray.length-1;}
    else
    {
        i=i-1;
    }


       document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i];


}
```

And the JSFiddle link in which i have the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/96azU/1/

Comment: If the answer helps you, then please accept my answer and vote up.

Comment: I don't have enough reps but certainly this the answer I was waiting for! Thanks alot.

Comment: I'm new to stacks but I understand what you are saying now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 var myArray = ["black","yellow","black","red","blue"];

 var i = 0;

 function forward(){
   if (myArray.length == i) i = 0;

   document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i++];
 };

 function backward(){
   if (i == -1) i = myArray.length - 1;

   document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.backgroundColor = myArray[i--];
 };
```

Comment: although what matters is the last position of the color, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user2887761 even the last position of the color is corrected in my answer